# portfolio blog hosting

Tags: php, web-development, open-source, blog

We currently have a photo storage website. A user can store his photos on our site. We want to give a facility to each user to create his photo portfolio and customize its look and feel, and contents more like a blog hosting. I am very beginner here. Is there any open source software that I can use?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try WordPress (http://wordpress.org/). It's an extremely easy to set up blog software that allows multiple accounts as well as posting Images and Video. If you a beginner may be the easiest software to setup/use. Not sure exactly what your trying to accomplish, but I hope it helps!

Comment: I was looking into wordpress. That is what i wanted to know that whether it allows multiple accounts. I will try it. Thanks

Comment: +1, but [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) would be better for a more advanced user

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of open source blog software options, but what you describe seems more to do with the visuals of your exiting site and not blogging.

What you need probably is a way for users to modify the CSS file associated with their portfolio, perhaps with a GUI or if you have technical users just a straight file upload.

Some open source blog options if I misread your needs:

- Wordpress
- Movable Type
- b2evolution
- BlogEngine.Net
- LifeType
- Toto